# How can I cache this api response between restarts?

Tags: swift, caching, core-data, nsuserdefaults

The branding scheme of my app is set using an api response that contains 2 strings.

Imagine something like: `{ primary: "#3eab5c", secondary: "#1fb3b7" }`

I'd like to cache the values, so should a user ever open my app with no connectivity or perhaps my branding api is unavailable, then I can continue to render using the correct colours.

My first thought would be to store these as key value pairs in `UserDefaults` and retrieve them as and when needed.

I'm not sure if this is best practice and perhaps I should be using `CoreData` to cache the original response?

If `CoreData` is the best bet, how can I cache my api response there?

Comment: You can simply save/fetch it in `UserDefaults` in form of `Data`. `CoreData` will just increase the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `save/fetch` the response in `UserDefaults` in form of `Data`.

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var primary: String?
    var secondary: String?
}
let response = Response(primary: "#3eab5c", secondary: "#1fb3b7")

//Saving
if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(response) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "CachedResponse")
}

//Fetching
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "CachedResponse") {
    let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(response)
}
```

You can definitely use `CoreData` for storing your response. But it doesn't seem your case need it.